# What is the difference between os.Stdout and syscall.Stdout?

Tags: go, stdout, system-calls

I have been trying to work ForkExec() and I am not able to get this one work, is there a difference between syscall.Stdout and os.Stdout?

Here is a small example of the code I am trying to run.

```
command := "/usr/bin/echo"
args := []string{"Hello there."}
attr := new(syscall.ProcAttr)
attr.Env = os.Environ()
attr.Files = []uintptr{uintptr(syscall.Stdin), uintptr(syscall.Stdout), uintptr(syscall.Stderr)}
pid , err := syscall.ForkExec(command, args, attr)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(pid)
```

The output is not showing up on the screen.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.Stdout` is a `*os.File`. It works with go functions that want an `io.Writer` or similar interfaces. `syscall.Stdout` is an integer constant. It's the *file descriptor number* of stdout, which is useful for low-level syscalls.

`syscall.ForkExec` does indeed want file descriptor numbers... but it's unclear why you're using that instead of `os/exec.Cmd` which is much more straightforward.

Comment: I have been trying to make a multiprocess application, syscall.ForkExec happens to be threadsafe, and I am trying to understand how this works, what I am doing wrong here. I am just trying things from the examples on the internet. Can you recommend, me how to work with this, I think I know how os/exec.cmd will work. Want to know how thread safe applications can be made.

Comment: @SupreetSingh you're thinking about completely the wrong stuff. Use `exec.Cmd`, it uses `ForkExec` internally and it's exactly as safe as you need it to be.

Comment: Thank you sir, I got it to work, I took your advice and used exec.Cmd. I have been coding in C and C++, for a year now, and I find Golang to be extremely confusing at times. How do I get better at this? I am making a project with it right now. Can you recommend me something that will help me develop more understanding of it.